# Markdown renderer for answers does not match what is posted when no newline is included before a table

Tags: bug, status-review

I was writing [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/58593/16533) and noticed that when I went to post it, the second table (which looked exactly as it currently does as posted) suddenly was no longer formatted as a table.

I was able to fix this by adding a newline between what I had as the table header/title and the Markdown for the table, which was good.  However, the preview was showing the intended formatting the entire time, despite the resulting post not containing the table.

### Reproducing the bug:

I will attempt to reproduce this behavior below:

---

Table 1 (works great)

| Column 1 | Column 2 |
| --- | --- |
| test 1 | test2 |

---

Table 2 (Looks great in renderer)
| Column 1| Column 2 |
|-|-|
| test 1 |  test2 |

---

### View from formatter:

[image: Preview showing "correct"/intended formatting]

---

### View in post:

[image: Resulting post with the table formatting removed]

Comment: Posting it here has an almost 100% chance that SE will not notice at all. Its probably better to bring this to Meta SE or Meta SO in order to get the devs to look at it. (btw, that is not your mistake, it been frustrating that SE as company doesn't really see anything outside SO).

Comment: Ah, thanks @Polygnome, I wasn’t certain and [this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306075/bug-report-submitting#comment247099_306078) suggested that it doesn’t matter where, and I also wasn’t sure if it was a sure-dependent bug. Is there a way to migrate it? Or should I close/delete and re-post on the main Meta site?

Comment: Given that this has already been reported as a bug on Meta SE, it's a bit pointless to migrate or repost there.

Comment: @fyrepenguin Don't close or migrate. Since Franck's post never made it into the review queue for some reason, I have added yours. You can tell by the [tag:status-review] tag I added above.

Comment: Yeah, @DavidHammen, at the time I didn’t realize there was a dupe on the main meta.

Answer (score 5):

This issue was reported on Meta SE as a bug report a year ago: [Markdown preview doesn't match post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/358999/178179)

It hasn't been fixed yet.

Comment: Not only has it not yet been fixed, your report apparently has not yet even been acknowledged as a bug. It is strange that the preview and as-posted MarkDown renderers must use slightly different code bases.

Comment: Well, I can't control what goes into review over there, but I can here. So I'll add this post to the review queue.

Comment: @DavidHammen and also got downvoted a bit...

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt That happens on meta. You did get more upvotes than downvotes.

Comment: @DavidHammen True, and I can't say that for all my valid bug reports. No good deed goes unpunished.